# Using the Heaviside function to represent a given graph

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

The question is the following:

[image]

The graph is zero between $0$ and $2$, is a straight line from the point $(2,0)$ to $(5,5)$, a straight line down from $(5,5)$ to $(4,0)$ and zero everywhere else.

So far, my attempt is: $\dfrac{5t}{3}[(u(t-2)-u(t-5))-(u(t-5)-u(t-8))]$ where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside function. I have chosen the slope of $\dfrac{5t}{3}$ since $(5,5) - (2,0) = (3,5)$ so the rise over run is $\dfrac{5}{3}.$

Any help would be appreciated on where I went wrong.

EDIT: My slope is incorrect... I have corrected this now.

Comment: Define the function piecewise, and then use u function to add them together without intefering

Comment: So that's what I"ve done already. I have broken up the intervals into [0,2], (2,5), and [5, 8] as you can see from my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming every square is 1 unit in your picture.

The first line is

$$\frac 53 (t-2)$$

Second lin eis

$$-\frac 53 (t-8)$$

Which gives:

$$\frac{1}{3} (5 (t-2)) (\theta (t-2)-\theta (t-5))-\frac{1}{3} (5 (t-8)) (\theta (t-5)-\theta (t-8))$$

Comment: Okay but how did you decide on that? How did you decide on $\dfrac{5}{3}$ as the slope?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/9LKuPq2.jpg Slope is tangent

Comment: Thank you. The trouble was that I got my coordinate wrong for the apex of the triangle.

Comment: No, your solution was incorrect altogether. https://i.imgur.com/xI4CeG6.png

Comment: Sure, but the reason for that is that I had my slope set-up incorrectly due to the incorrect coordinate for the apex.